# What are the options for securely accessing on-premises REST API through AWS API Gateway and NLB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, aws-nlb

We are using an AWS API Gateway to route requests between newly built lambdas and on-premise REST APIs. It's a slow but gradual migration from a third party API Gateway to AWS.

The issue is calling cross VPCs within AWS is fine. It's VPC Link to NLB to target.

However calling from APIG-Gateway to VPC-Link to NLB to On-Premise is proving an issue.

We are using Direct Connect to link on-prem to AWS.

The issue is the IP of the target API is not in the NLB range.

The AWS is very secure with developer and SEN role separation.

A VPN Proxy is not an option neither is an NLB open to the internet.

The other option we have is wrap the calls to the REST API sitting on-prem in a lambda - sort of a proxy pass through - this will allow the lambda to discover the IP in the VPC.

Sorry if this is not well articulated but that is the jist of it.

Any ideas to solve this elegantly?

Tried an API Gateway to VPC Link to NLB to reach on-prem.